# Is it possible to have a local reverse proxy using nginx docker and nextjs?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have two projects in NextJS one starting at localhost:3000 and one at localhost:4000.

I would like to know if its possible using separated Docker container with nginx to run a reverse proxy and have custom domains like mydomain.local and auth.mydomain.local and when I go in browser and type mydomain.local to start localhost:3000 and when I type auth.mydomain.local to start localhost:4000.

for now my nginx.conf looks like this

```
worker_processes 1;

events { 
    worker_connections 1024; 
}

http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.local;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name auth.mydomain.local;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }

}
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: reverse_proxy
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    external: true
```

also my Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

# Expose port 80 for incoming connections
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Andromeda basically I get 502 Bad Gateway when I try to access mydomain.local but everything works fine if I use localhost:3000 or mydomain.local:3000

Comment: Could you please add `access.log` or possible `error.log` for `curl -I --location mydomain.local`?